# Validate the inputs and perform actions accordingly

Tags: java, validation, design-patterns

I have two proceses on which I need to validate on few fields.

- For `ProcessA` class, I need to validate on few fields. Basis on those fields I will validate this class.
- For `ProcessB` class, I need to validate on different fields. And if those fields are valid, then I will validate this class.

Both my processes should pass `GenericRecord` to `Validator` class and now depending on whether it is `ProcessA` or `ProcessB`, my `Validator` class should validate those fields.

- For ProcessA, I need to validate on `clientId`, `deviceId`, `payId`.
- For ProcessB, I need to validate on `crossId`, `maxId`, `minId`.

I am able to make it work for ProcessA but I am confuse how does my `Validator` class will look like for `ProcessB` fields validation. Confusion is how does `Validator` class decide that I need to validate fields for ProcessA or ProcessB as soon as it receives `GenericRecord` in the constructor. If `ProcessA` GenericRecord is passed, then do validation on ProcessA fields or If `ProcessB` GenericRecord is passed, then do validation on ProcessB fields.

**ProcessA**

```
try {
  GenericRecordDomainDataDecoder decoder = new GenericRecordDomainDataDecoder(config);
  while (true) {
    ConsumerRecords<byte[], byte[]> records = consumer.poll(1000);
    for (ConsumerRecord<byte[], byte[]> record : records) {
      GenericRecord payload = decoder.decode(record.value());
      String processName = "processA";
      // validation logic
      Validator validation = new Validator(payload);
      if(!validation.isValid())
          continue;

      // some other code
    }
  }
} catch (Exception ex) {
  // logging error
}
```

**ProcessB**

```
try {
  GenericRecordDomainDataDecoder decoder = new GenericRecordDomainDataDecoder(config);
  while (true) {
    ConsumerRecords<byte[], byte[]> records = consumer.poll(1000);
    for (ConsumerRecord<byte[], byte[]> record : records) {
      GenericRecord payload = decoder.decode(record.value());
      String processName = "processB";
      // validation logic
      Validator validation = new Validator(payload);
      if(!validation.isValid())
          continue;

      // some other code
    }
  }
} catch (Exception ex) {
  // logging error
}
```

Below is my Validator class which only works right now for `ProcessA` validation. I have added another constructor which I know doesn't work but just wanted to show what I want to do for `ProcessB`. And then I need to call `isValid` method that will tell me whether fields for ProcessB are present or not.

```
public class Validator {
  private String clientId, deviceId, payId;

  // for ProcessA
  public Validator(GenericRecord payload) {
    clientId = (String) DataUtils.parseRecord(payload, "clientId");
    deviceId = (String) DataUtils.parseRecord(payload, "deviceId");
    payId = (String) DataUtils.parseRecord(payload, "payId");
  }

  // for ProcessB, I know this doesn't work - just wanted to show the idea
  public Validator(GenericRecord payload) {
    crossId = (String) DataUtils.parseRecord(payload, "crossId");
    maxId = (String) DataUtils.parseRecord(payload, "maxId");
    minId = (String) DataUtils.parseRecord(payload, "minId");
  }

  // this is what I am calling for ProcessA
  public boolean isValid() {
    return isValidClientIdDeviceId() && isValidPayId();
  }

  private boolean isValidPayId() {
    if (payId == null) {
      logger.log("invalid payId.");
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  private boolean isValidClientIdDeviceId() {
    if (clientId == null && deviceId == null) {
      logger.log("invalid clientId and deviceId.");
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  // getters
}
```

I can pass another parameter `processName` which is a String to `Validator` class. Can we use that to achieve this to validate fields accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first solution I propose to you is acceptable if you have few of type of Process class.

You could have a empty constructor and have a init method by Process you invoke after the constructor.

Just keep the default constructor (don't need to declare that):

```
  public Validator() {   
  }

  // for ProcessA
  public initProcessA(GenericRecord payload) {
    clientId = (String) DataUtils.parseRecord(payload, "clientId");
    deviceId = (String) DataUtils.parseRecord(payload, "deviceId");
    payId = (String) DataUtils.parseRecord(payload, "payId");
  }

  // for ProcessB, 
  public void initProcessB(GenericRecord payload) {
    crossId = (String) DataUtils.parseRecord(payload, "crossId");
    maxId = (String) DataUtils.parseRecord(payload, "maxId");
    minId = (String) DataUtils.parseRecord(payload, "minId");
  }
```

In Process A :

```
   Validator validation = new Validator();
   validation.initProcessA(payload);
```

In Process B :

```
   Validator validation = new Validator();
   validation.initProcessB(payload);
```

This first solution has its limits. 
If you have validation specificities that depends on the `Process` class, a better solution would be to explode the rules with a distinct validator class for each Process because it would be more maintainable.

You could have for example :

```
public abstract class Validator<T extends Process>{

   ...
   // common and abstract methods    
   ...
   public abstract boolean isValid();
}
```

Validator A for Process A :

```
public class ValidatorA extends Validator<ProcessA>{
   ...
        public ValidatorA(GenericRecord payload){
           clientId = (String) DataUtils.parseRecord(payload, "clientId");
           deviceId = (String) DataUtils.parseRecord(payload, "deviceId");
           payId = (String) DataUtils.parseRecord(payload, "payId");
        }

       public  boolean isValid(){
           // validation rules specific to ProcessA
       }
    ...

}
```

Validator B for Process B :

```
public class ValidatorB extends Validator<ProcessB>{
   ...
      public ValidatorB(GenericRecord payload) {
         crossId = (String) DataUtils.parseRecord(payload, "crossId");
         maxId = (String) DataUtils.parseRecord(payload, "maxId");
         minId = (String) DataUtils.parseRecord(payload, "minId");
      }

      public  boolean isValid(){
          // validation rules specific to ProcessB
      }

   ...
}
```

Comment: With the first solution, how does my isValid method looks like then? I mean isValid then need to know as well that I need to validate fields for ProcessA or ProcessB?

Comment: in your actual code, `isValid()` is common for both Processes. If it not desirable, I think you should follow the second solution where you have a abstract `Validator` class and a concrete `Validator` class by type of Process. In this way, you could define in each concrete `Validator`class the required specificities for validating.

Comment: `isValid()` can be common for both processes, my confusion is let's say I did `initProcessB` so how does isValid method will know that it should validate fields for ProcessB only. Right now it just validates field for ProcessA. So if I init for processB, I want isValid to validate fields for ProcessB only so that from my processB code, I can call isValid which will just validate fields for processB. There is no common field validation for both of my process, they all are different.

Comment: In this case `isValid()` has not the same behavior according to the process. So follow my advice in my previous comment. I have just given you more details in my answer about how you could do for the second solution.

Comment: I agree with you :) that's why, I posted the second solution before publishing my answer. Maybe, I would have removed the first solution before :)